# How are Green's Theorem, Stokes' Theorem, etc all connected together

Tags: linear-algebra, differential-geometry, vector-analysis, stokes-theorem, greens-theorem

I am trying to understand how the below listen mathematical theorems and functions are related to each other but the informations regarding this are scrabbled all over and it's getting confusing. The four major theorems at the culmination of multivariable calculus:

1. Green's theorem
2. 2D divergence theorem
3. Stokes' theorem
4. 3D Divergence theorem

Now I know:

Green's theorem is a 2D special case of Stokes' theorem, or said in another way Stokes' theorem is the 3d version of Green's theorem (I assume the sentences mean the same thing). (And the Stokes' theorem is a special case of the generalized stokes theorem regarding manifolds).

Now on Wikipedia this is what it is written regarding the Green's Theorem and the 2D divergence theorem:

"Considering only two-dimensional vector fields, Green's theorem is equivalent to the two-dimensional version of the divergence theorem"

Does this mean that the 2D case of the Stokes' theorem is nothing more than the 2D case of the divergence theorem?

Basically I'd like to know how each of the 4 mentioned theorems are related to each other!

Comment: greens functions? that is a totally different beast

Comment: Pl check out book Tristan needham visual differential geoemtry and forms

Comment: I think Spivak’s book on multi variable calculus covers this well.

Comment: These are all special cases of the [generalized Stokes theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generalized_Stokes_theorem).

Comment: On a conceptual level, they're all examples of the same idea that drives the Fundamental Theorem of Calculus: that arbitrarily small volume measurements cancel more and more so that in the limit, the only remaining terms are the valuations at the boundary.

Answer (score 1):

This is an old post, somewhat too general, but no other post gives an overview of how these theorems generalize, and this topic is worth the elaboration beyond naming the generalized Stokes' Theorem or naming a textbook on complex analysis.

While Grant Sanderson gives intuitive explanations of each of these theorems in his [Multivariable Calculus](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=TrcCbdWwCBc&list=PLSQl0a2vh4HC5feHa6Rc5c0wbRTx56nF7&pp=iAQB) series on YouTube, I thank Prof. Rick Presman for his exposition of the [Generalized Stokes’ Theorem](https://math.uchicago.edu/%7Emay/REU2012/REUPapers/Presman.pdf), and also Prof. Oliver Knill for his exposition via [Calculus in four dimensions](https://people.math.harvard.edu/%7Eknill/teaching/summer2020/handouts/lecture25.pdf).

And, Aleph Naught’s videos: [Stokes' Theorem on Manifolds](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1lGM5DEdMaw) and [The derivative isn't what you think it is](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2ptFnIj71SM) give intuition as to the Generalized Stokes' Theorem and perhaps differential geometry more broadly.

---

Here is the gist of Prof. Knill's exposition on generalized integration and, in turn, Stokes' Theorem.

*Note: Prof. Knill does not discuss chains, as this is made for students of multivariable calculus.*

First, the ladder from $1$-d to $4$-d.

In two dimensions, we see: the line integral $\int_{a}^{b} \mathbf{F}(\mathbf{r}(t)) \cdot \mathbf{r}'(t) \, dt$ and the double integral $\iint_{G} f(u, v) \, du \, dv$.

In three dimensions, in addition to the line integral, we have the flux integral $\iint_{G} \mathbf{F}(\mathbf{r}(u, v)) \cdot (\mathbf{r}_u \times \mathbf{r}_v) \, du \, dv$ and the triple integral $\iiint_{G} f(u, v, w) \, du \, dv \, dw$.

To express these integrals using differential forms, we can consider forms with one component for simplicity, but it is straightforward to extend to sums by linearity.

I cannot make Prof. Knill's exposition and notation here more concise:

> For a $1$-form $F = A \, dx$, we integrate $$ \int_{a}^{b}
>  A(\mathbf{r}(u)) \, x'(u) \, du. $$
>
> For a $2$-form $F = A \, dx \, dy$, we integrate $$ \iint_{G}
>  A(\mathbf{r}(u, v)) \det \left(\begin{array}{cc} (\mathbf{r}_u)_1 &
>  (\mathbf{r}_v)_1 \\ (\mathbf{r}_u)_2 & (\mathbf{r}_v)_2 \\
>  \end{array}\right) \, du \, dv. $$
>
> For a $3$-form $F = A \, dx \, dy \, dz$, we integrate $$ \iiint_{G}
>  A(\mathbf{r}(u, v, w)) \det \left(\begin{array}{ccc} (\mathbf{r}_u)_1
>  & (\mathbf{r}_v)_1 & (\mathbf{r}_w)_1 \\ (\mathbf{r}_u)_2 &
>  (\mathbf{r}_v)_2 & (\mathbf{r}_w)_2 \\ (\mathbf{r}_u)_3 &
>  (\mathbf{r}_v)_3 & (\mathbf{r}_w)_3 \\ \end{array}\right) \, du \, dv
>  \, dw. $$
>
> This determinant is the triple scalar product of the three column
> vectors. So, we can still work in principle without having seen any
> linear algebra course.
>
> For example, for $F = B \, dy$, we would compute the line integral as
> $$ \int_{a}^{b} B(\mathbf{r}(u)) \, y'(u) \, du. $$
>
> And for $F = A \, dx \, dz \, dt$, we would compute the hyper flux as
> $$ \iiint_{G} A(\mathbf{r}(u, v, w)) \det \left(\begin{array}{ccc}
>  (\mathbf{r}_u)_1 & (\mathbf{r}_v)_1 & (\mathbf{r}_w)_1 \\
>  (\mathbf{r}_u)_3 & (\mathbf{r}_v)_3 & (\mathbf{r}_w)_3 \\
>  (\mathbf{r}_u)_4 & (\mathbf{r}_v)_4 & (\mathbf{r}_w)_4 \\
>  \end{array}\right) \, du \, dv \, dw. $$

A $k$-form $F$ assigns, to each point $\mathbf{x}$, a $k$-linear anti-symmetric map. It can be represented as $F(\mathbf{x}) \cdot (\mathbf{v}_1, \ldots, \mathbf{v}_k)$, which yields a number. The maps $\mathbf{v}_j \mapsto F(\mathbf{x}) \cdot (\mathbf{v}_1, \ldots, \mathbf{v}_k)$ are linear, and for any pair $i$, $j$, we have $F(\mathbf{x}) \cdot (\mathbf{v}_1, \ldots, \mathbf{v}_i, \mathbf{v}_j, \ldots, \mathbf{v}_k) = -F(\mathbf{x}) \cdot (\mathbf{v}_1, \ldots, \mathbf{v}_j, \mathbf{v}_i, \ldots, \mathbf{v}_k)$.

Let $\mathbf{r}: G \rightarrow \mathbf{r}(G)$ be a parametrization, where $G$ is a $k$-dimensional region mapped into $\mathbb{R}^4$. We can assign to each point $\mathbf{x} = \mathbf{r}(\mathbf{u})$ the number $F(\mathbf{x}) \, d\mathbf{u} = F(\mathbf{x}) \cdot (\mathbf{r}_u^1, \ldots, \mathbf{r}_u^k)$. The flux of the $k$-form through the $k$-surface $\mathbf{r}(G)$ is then defined as $\int_{G} F(\mathbf{r}(\mathbf{u})) \cdot d\mathbf{u}$.

A $1$-form $F=A \ dx$, gives a line integral $\int_{a}^{b} F(\mathbf{r}(t)) \cdot \mathbf{r}'(t) \, dt$.

A $2$-form $F=A \ dx \ dy$, gives a flux integral $\iint_{G} F(\mathbf{r}(u, v)) \cdot (\mathbf{r}_u, \mathbf{r}_v) \, du \, dv$.

A $3$-form $F=A \ dx \ dy \ dt$, gives a hyper flux integral $\iiint_{G} F(\mathbf{r}(u, v, w)) \cdot (\mathbf{r}_u, \mathbf{r}_v, \mathbf{r}_w) \, du \, dv \, dw$.

A $4$-form $F = A \ dx \, dy \, dz \, dt$, gives a volume integral $\iint \iint_{G} F(x, y, z, t) \, dx \, dy \, dz \, dt$.

---

Now, $4$-d to $k$-d

In four dimensions, we have four integral theorems.

The fundamental theorem of line integrals:

$$\int_a^b df(\mathbf{r}(t)) \cdot \frac{d\mathbf{r}}{dt}(u) \, du = f(\mathbf{r}(b)) - f(\mathbf{r}(a))$$

Stokes' theorem for a region $G$ with boundary $C$:

$$\iint_G d\mathbf{F}(\mathbf{r}(u, v)) \cdot \left(\frac{\partial\mathbf{r}}{\partial u}, \frac{\partial\mathbf{r}}{\partial v}\right) \, dudv = \int_C \mathbf{F}(\mathbf{r}(u)) \cdot \frac{d\mathbf{r}}{du}(u) \, du$$

The hyper Stokes' theorem:

$$\iiint_G d\mathbf{F}(\mathbf{r}(u, v, w)) \cdot \left(\frac{\partial\mathbf{r}}{\partial u}, \frac{\partial\mathbf{r}}{\partial v}, \frac{\partial\mathbf{r}}{\partial w}\right) \, dudvdw = \iint_{\delta G} \mathbf{F}(\mathbf{r}(u, v)) \cdot \left(\frac{\partial\mathbf{r}}{\partial u}, \frac{\partial\mathbf{r}}{\partial v}\right) \, dudv$$

The divergence theorem:

$$\iint \iint_G d\mathbf{F}(\mathbf{x, y, z, t}) \, dxdydzdt = \iiint_{\delta G} \mathbf{F}(\mathbf{r}(u, v, w)) \cdot \left(\frac{\partial\mathbf{r}}{\partial u}, \frac{\partial\mathbf{r}}{\partial v}, \frac{\partial\mathbf{r}}{\partial w}\right) \, dudvdw$$

All these integral theorems fall under:

$$\int_G d\mathbf{F} = \int_{\delta G} \mathbf{F}$$

where $\mathbf{F}$ is a $k$-form and $G$ is a $(k - 1)$-dimensional surface.

The 4-dimensional framework extends to higher dimensions with more variables and larger determinant matrices. Confusion arises in 2 and 3 dimensions due to the identification of different spaces, attempting to fuse ideas that 4-d shows to be distinct.

---

Since Prof. Knill's exposition of Stokes' theorem relies on forms and exterior derivatives, here's some of his exposition on those.

Differential forms relate to graphs $(V, E)$ with vertices $V$ and edges $E$, where $k$-cliques represent fully connected groups, and a $k$-form $F$ is a function on oriented $k$-cliques. The boundary $\delta x$ of a clique $x$ consists of compatible subcliques obtained by removing one member, with dimensions determined by the number of members minus one. E.g. a triangle $x = (a, b, c)$, its boundary $\delta x$ includes three 1-dimensional edges $(b, c), (c, a), (a, b)$.

The exterior derivative $df(x)$ sums up values of $f$ on the boundary $\delta x$. Stokes' theorem holds: $df(x) = f(\delta x)$. A $k$-dimensional surface $G$ consists of oriented $k$-dimensional cliques. The integral $\int_G F$ represents the $k$-dimensional flux. Stokes' theorem simplifies to $\int_G dF = \int_{\delta G} F$. The space of $k$-forms is $f_k$-dimensional ($f_k$ is the number of $k$-dimensional cliques). The exterior derivatives are represented by matrices $d_k$. The overall exterior derivative is a matrix $d= \sum_{k=0}^{d} f_k$.

E.g. the Dirac operator is $D = d + d^*$, and the Laplacian is $L = D^2 = d^*d + dd^*$.

---

That is a summary of the clearest exposition of the generalized Stokes' Theorem I have found. I recommend reading Prof. Knill's article linked above. He goes on to very briefly relate PDE's, which Prof. Steve Brunton does well in his [YouTube Series](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Jt5R-Tm8cV8&list=PLMrJAkhIeNNQromC4WswpU1krLOq5Ro6S&pp=iAQB).